# Unable to read text from options in the Select dropdown list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get all the option elements from the dropdown list and display the text of each option in the dropdown. But the text is not getting displayed. How to get the text for the options in the dropdown list?

This is what i have tried so far :

```
 WebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
 d.navigate().to("https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales.jsp?d=70130000000EqoP&internal=true");

 Select s = new Select(d.findElement(By.id("CompanyEmployees")));

 List<WebElement> options = s.getOptions();

 for(WebElement option : options){
   System.out.println(option.getAttribute("title"));
   System.out.println(option.getText());
 }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <li class=" type-select">
        <div class="control-container ">
        <div class="label">
                <span class="required-marker">*</span>
            <label for="CompanyEmployees" id="CompanyEmployees_lbl">Employees</label>
        </div>

          <div class="field">
        <select name="CompanyEmployees" id="CompanyEmployees">
             <option value="">Employees</option>
                                                        <option value="3" title="1 - 5 employees">1 - 5 employees</option>
            <option value="12" title="6 - 20 employees">6 - 20 employees</option>
            <option value="50" title="21 - 100 employees">21 - 100 employees</option>
            <option value="250" title="101 - 500 employees">101 - 500 employees</option>
            <option value="2000" title="501 - 3,500 employees">501 - 3,500 employees</option>
            <option value="3500" title="3,501+ employees">3,501+ employees</option>
            </select>

</div>
    <div class="info">
        <label for="CompanyEmployees__c" id="CompanyEmployees_lel">Select the number of employees</label>
                <img src="https://secure2.sfdcstatic.com/common/assets/images/error-icon.png" alt="" border="0">
    </div>
</div></li>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code ans its working fine.I am able to see the text is getting printed on my console. Which webdriver version you are using? I checked it on version 2.38.

Comment: the text that is displayed is from the attribute 'title'.  not the text of the option.

Comment: Tried after removing sysout for 'Title'. Its working fine at my end. I am able to see the options getting printed on console.

Comment: may i know which version of selenium you are using. i will give a try with that

Comment: version 2.38.0 and firefox 26.0

Comment: how you are running your tests?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
        Select sel = new Select(element);
        List<WebElement> list =  sel.getOptions();
        for(int i=0;i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
        }
```

Also if possible post the html code. If the drop down does not contain select tag it is not possible to use select class.

Comment: tried your code. still text is not getting displayed. Here is the link for the page which has the select element:  https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales.jsp?d=70130000000EqoP&internal=true

Comment: Can you paste the html. Would help to find out if any changes has to be made. Also the browser and the selenium version.

Comment: Selenium-java-2.39.0 and Firefox 26.0

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='CompanyEmployees']//option"));
for (WebElement element : elements) {
        element.getText();
    }
```

Or:

```
WebElement yourSelect = driver.findElement(By.id("CompanyEmployees"));
List<WebElement> elements = new Select(yourSelect).getOptions();
for (WebElement element : elements) {
    element.getText();
}
```

How to get select option text:

```
WebElement yourSelect = driver.findElement(By.id("CompanyEmployees"));
String text = new Select(yourSelect ).getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```